# How to access request attribute inside display tag in JSP in struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag

I have set an arraylist in my action class as below

```
    public class Student {

        public String execute()  {

        List students_list = new ArrayList(); 

        //business service that fetches students 
        students_list = studentService.getStudents(); 

        request.setAttribute("StudentList", students_list);

        return "listStudents";
     } 
}
```

In my jsp I am accessing it as below

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/displaytag-12.tld" prefix="display" %>

    <display:table uid= "studentTable" name="%{#request.StudentList}" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" styleClass="data" width="100%" export="true" requestURI="listStudents.action">

        <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />   

        <display:setProperty name="basic.show.StudentList" value="false" />

        <display:setProperty name="css.th.sortable" value="centbold" />

        <display:setProperty name="css.th.sorted" value="centbold" />

        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="StudentList.xls" />

        <display:setProperty name="export.banner">
            ...........................................
            ...........................................

    </display:table>
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="listStudents" class="com.students.action.Student">
    <result name="listStudents">/jsp/listStudents.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I have added the **displaytag-1.0.jar** to the WEB-INF/lib folder of the project also.

The table is not displaying in the jsp(blank jsp). 
 May I know how to resolve this?
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the uri

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>
```

You need these jar files

1. commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
2. commons-collections-3.1.jar
3. commons-lang-2.3.jar
4. displaytag-1.2.jar
5. itext-1.3.jar
6. jcl104-over-slf4j-1.4.2.jar
7. log4j-1.2.13.jar
8. poi-3.2-FINAL.jar
9. slf4j-api-1.4.2.jar
10. slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar

Use this CSS

STYLE.CSS

```
table {     border: 1px solid #666;     width: 80%;     margin: 20px 0 20px 0 !important; } th,td {     padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px !important;    text-align: left;   vertical-align: top; } thead tr {   background-color: #999999; } th.sorted {    background-color: #CCCCCC; } th a,th a:visited {    color: black; } th a:hover {    text-decoration: underline;     color: black; } th.sorted a,th.sortable a {     background-position: right;     display: block;     width: 100%; } tr.odd {     background-color: #fff } tr.tableRowEven,tr.even {  background-color: #CCCCCC } .group-1 { font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:10px; border-top:1px solid black; } .group-2 { font-style:italic; border-top: 1px solid black; } .grouped-table tr.even { background-color: #fff; } .grouped-table tr.odd { background-color: #fff; }
```

Comment: I changed it but still getting blank JSP.

Comment: It's id not uid in the display tag for the table attribute

Comment: I changed it to uid, still I get blank jsp. Is displaytag-1.0.jar compatible with struts 2 framework

Comment: I said change it to id not uid

Comment: Sorry changed it to id only & does displaytag-1.0 jar has any dependency jars?

Comment: You need these jar files 
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar commons-collections-3.1.jar commons-lang-2.3.jar displaytag-1.2.jar itext-1.3.jar jcl104-over-slf4j-1.4.2.jar log4j-1.2.13.jar poi-3.2-FINAL.jar slf4j-api-1.4.2.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

I found that displaytag-1.0.jar is not supported with struts 2 framework. 

 **Solution** :

- Add the latest jar - displaytag-1.2.jar.    This jar has a dependency
  on commons-lang-2.x jar so this jar also should be in WEB-INF/lib folder.
- With JSP 2.0 and displaytag-1.2.jar, there is no need of displaytag-12.tld in WEB-INF folder.
- In JSP, include <%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>
- To access request attribute in display tag, just use

  `<display:table uid= "studentTable" name="StudentList">` 
   where "StudentList" is the request attribute set in the action class.
- Add displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar to lib folder if export to **CSV|XML|EXCEL** is required for display table.